# Get coordinates for multiple streetaddresses in one function

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to generate google maps, and need to find the coordinates for each marker, based on the street address. It find the coordinates fine, but it only give me coordinates for the "the last" entered street address. I need an array for each of them.

HTML:

```
<div class="gmapItems">
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapCity" value='New York'>
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapAddress">
<textarea class="input-medium googleMapInformation" value='1'></textarea>
</div>

<div class="gmapItems">
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapCity" value='Boston'>
<input type="text" class="input-medium googleMapAddress">
<textarea class="input-medium googleMapInformation" value='1'></textarea>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#AddGoogleMap").on('click', function () {            
    mapMarkers = new Array();
    $('.gmapItems').each(function(){
    gmapInfo = $('.googleMapInformation',this).val();       

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    address = $('.googleMapCity',this).val(), $('.googleMapAddress',this).val();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longitude);
      }
    }); 

    mapMarkers.push("["+"'"+gmapInfo+"'", latitude, longitude+"]"); 
    });
    alert(mapMarkers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding is asynchronous.  You need to use the data inside the callback routine (where it is available).  If you indent your code in a reasonable manner, you can see where that is:

```
$("#AddGoogleMap").on('click', function () {            
  mapMarkers = new Array();
  $('.gmapItems').each(function(){
  gmapInfo = $('.googleMapInformation',this).val();       

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  address = $('.googleMapCity',this).val(), $('.googleMapAddress',this).val();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longitude);
      mapMarkers.push("["+"'"+gmapInfo+"'", latitude, longitude+"]"); 
    } else {
      alert("Geocoding failed: " + status);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Your `alert(mapMarkers)` won't make sense until all the results have been returned from Google's server, after it has executed in your current code.